# elastalert search for a string in logstash

Tags: elasticsearch

Need help in writing query for searching particular phrase and when it matches with it , it should throw and alert. I am using the following , but I think it is not matching for the phrase and sending alerts:

```
es_host: elasticsearch.internal   
es_port: 9200   
name: Example rule  
type: frequency  
index: logstash-* 
num_events: 50  
timeframe: 
    hours: 4  
query:  
    query_string:  
        "message" : "this is a test string"  # (Required) 
# The alert is use when a match is found 
alert: - "slack" - "debug" 
slack: 
    slack_webhook_url: 'hooks.slack.com/services/abcd'.
```

The phrase is not present at all in log file but also it is sending alerts.

How to solve this issue?

Comment: That is not a phrase query. I suggest testing that query outside Elastalert and see how it behaves. Then go back to your Elastalert configuration with the properly tested query.

Comment: @AndreiStefan hi stefan , i am very new new to elastalert , i am trying search for a exact match for string in logstash,like "this is a test string". when this is found should throw an alert , can you help solve the issue ,thanks, if i am not following the correct process , please guide me resolving this.

Comment: Could you share your elastic search attributes and message format details?

Comment: HI Manik , what are the search attributes and message details. where we have to define them.can you please share me a example rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct way of writing a query is like this, could you please try this?

```
 filter:
 - query:
    query_string:
      query: "message: this is a test string"
```

This will only look for "this is a test string" in your message field. If that is not the exact string you are looking for try playing around with some regex or wildcards.

Comment: hi Manik, i need some help, i was trying to write a query to search for string ,but i am getting alert if it doesn't matches exactly ,ies_host: elasticsearch.internal
es_port: 9200
name: ENV04 Error alert
type: frequency
index: logstash-*
num_events: 1
timeframe:
    hours: 2000
#analyze_wildcard: true
filter:
- query:
    query_string:
      query: "message: error\\: Internal server error caught in app"
      minimum_should_match: "98%"

Comment: @ramakrishna do you want to post it as question?